# Why isn't Diep.io loading?

Tags: technical-issues, diep.io

I have just got on to [diep.io](https://diep.io), and it is stuck on the "Connecting" screen. The tab also keeps refreshing. I see many errors on my developer tools when I press the `F12` key.

I am using a Windows 10 Surface Laptop and Microsoft Edge. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about an internet browser problem.

Comment: @Joachim I think we should allow this question since diep.io is a browser game.

Comment: My view on this type of question has long been that the question is on-topic only if its actually specific to the game and not a generic computer or browser issue manifesting through a game. This question seems like the latter to me.

Comment: @pppery, I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to let everyone here know, I have solved the problem. It turns out the issue was that my LastPass extension was blocking [diep.io](https://diep.io) from working properly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

There are literally dozens of reasons why Diep.io may not be correctly loading. All we can really do is troubleshoot the problem; as we rule at certain things, we can pinpoint the problem, and ultimately have it resolved.

1. **Make sure you are using the correct weblink.** Ensure that the link you are using is https://diep.io. This is the link you should be using, and older links may cause problems.
2. **Make sure you have Internet access.** This goes without saying, but check that you can move to other websites, such as [Google](https://www.google.com).
3. **Try another web browser.** Check if you can access the game from another browser. I always recommend [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com.au/intl/en_au/chrome/). As an IT professional I would not recommend using Windows Edge to my worst enemy.
4. **Make sure your web browser is updated.** Out of date web browsers cause problems. Make sure you're using an up to date browser. If you are unsure of how to update your web browser, there are easy to follow guides for [Microsoft Edge](https://www.howtogeek.com/672726/how-to-update-microsoft-edge/), [Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), [Mozilla Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-release), [Opera](https://www.opera.com/computer/beta) and [Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204416).
5. **Make sure the site isn't down.** It is entirely possible that the site is just down. You can always ask a friend to check; alternatively, it might work on another device, so you know it must be up. If you don't have the means to check, try looking them up on [isitdownrightnow.com](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/). This will tell you if the site is responsive to an external source.

---

If all this fails, I usually recommend getting in touch with technical support. I can't find any, for this game.

We might be able to provide more help if you give us more information. Firstly, make sure you try the game on Google Chrome. I say this because we need to use this browser for the next steps.

Open the game in Google Chrome, and press <kbd>F12</kbd>. This will bring up the developer console. Select *"Console"* from the horizontal tabs along the top, and look at the screen that comes up. Depending on your expertise, you may be able to use this information to solve the problem by yourself; but you could also take a screenshot of this information and include it in your question to provide us more specific information about your unique situation.

[image]

Comment: Edge isn't so bad anymore now that it's chromium based. Not that I'd ever recommend anyone use it, but it's definitely no IE.

Comment: I figured this out, it turns out the LastPass extension was blocking diep.io from working.

Comment: When I opened the console, there were a bunch of errors there too, but they didn't get fixed until I disabled LastPass.